Integrate Okta with Slack + AWS Chatbot
I have integrated the AWS Chatbot service with Slack to manage my AWS resources using Slack commands. Now I'd like to add Okta SSO authentication. So, all users could get authenticated with Okta first, and then utilise Slack to access AWS resources.
Is there any way to configure this?
I tried seeking solutions on the internet but couldn't locate any feasible ones.
